# WooCommerce critical error: Call to undefined method WC_Product_Simple::get_variation_price()

Tags: php, woocommerce, methods, product

Recently I noticed some critical errors on my WooCommerce website. There are no orders since this problem has occurred.

When I go to WooCommerce -> Status -> Logs, I can see many errors that happen with a specific functions.

Here is the stack trace :

2023-06-01T08:39:58+00:00 CRITICAL Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method WC_Product_Simple::get_variation_price() in /home/clients/cbade695f2a03ed1b4e40db5c6bc9ad7/web/wp-content/themes/scolax/functions.php:28

Stack trace:
#0 /home/clients/cbade695f2a03ed1b4e40db5c6bc9ad7/web/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(308): wpnuls_text_before_price('<span class="wo...', Object(WC_Product_Simple))

#1 /home/clients/cbade695f2a03ed1b4e40db5c6bc9ad7/web/wp-includes/plugin.php(205): WP_Hook->apply_filters('<span class="wo...', Array)

#2 /home/clients/cbade695f2a03ed1b4e40db5c6bc9ad7/web/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-product.php(1880): apply_filters('woocommerce_get...', '<span class="wo...', Object(WC_Product_Simple))

#3 /home/clients/cbade695f2a03ed1b4e40db5c6bc9ad7/web/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/loop/price.php(25): WC_Product->get_price_html()

#4 /home/clients/cbade695f2a03ed1b4e40db5c6bc9ad7/web/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-core-functions.php(345): include('/home/clients/c...')

#5 /home/clients/c dans /home/clients/cbade695f2a03ed1b4e40db5c6bc9ad7/web/wp-content/themes/scolax/functions.php à la ligne 28

I would be grateful to get some help. Thanks !

Comment: Ok i will try this thank you ! i does not insert too much codes so i supected some plugins but maybe the theme is the culprit

Comment: It is related to some custom code you have inserted in your theme's functions.php file. The code related uses the method [`get_variation_price()`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/release/7.8/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-product-variable.php#L132-L144) and doesn't target specifically Variable products. So on other product types, this makes a Critical error. To avoid that, you need to target "variable" product type like in [this code line](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/release/7.8/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-structured-data.php#L221)

Comment: So you should provide in your question the related code function that is making this error (It uses the method `get_variation_price()` on line 28 in your theme's function.php file).